# Error executing "react-native link realm"

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to install realm to a react-native project (on Windows). I executed the following commands.

```
npm install --save realm
react-native link realm
```

I got the following error message - where `<Project-Folder>` is my project folder.

error EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '`<Project-Folder>`/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by executing the following command in Admin mode, i.e. you need to open cmd.exe as Administrator.

```
react-native link realm
```